# Why SpinLock doesn't support recursion

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, spinlock

I wonder why SpinLock doesn't support recursion.

Let's say I have a simple program with `Monitor` that locks and releases a block of instructions in a recursive way:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    private static void Recursion(int x)
    {
        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(lockObj, ref lockWasTaken);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (x > 0)
            {
                Recursion(x - 1);
            }
            if (lockWasTaken) Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Recursion(5);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If I do the same with SpinLock:

```
class Program
{
    private static SpinLock sl = new SpinLock(true);

    private static void Recursion(int x)
    {
        bool lockWasTaken = false;
        try
        {
            sl.Enter(ref lockWasTaken);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (x > 0)
            {
                Recursion(x - 1);
            }
            if (lockWasTaken) sl.Exit();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Recursion(5);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It throws an excpetion which says the calling thread already has a lock - and it is obviously true.
But my question is why `Monitor` can acquire a lock multiple times by the same thread while `SpinLock` cannot?
I can't find any reasons why a thread that has already locked a critical section can't enter it again.

Comment: If they were the same in all regards, they wouldn't need to be two separate things. The fact that it doesn't support recursion allows it to be *lighter weight*.

Comment: Because it is by design. Cleary, S (my emphasis):  _["Traditionally, recursive locks have been the default on Microsoft platforms. The `lock` statement, `Monitor`, `Mutex`, and `ReaderWriterLock` are all recursive. **However, newer types are starting to change this; `SpinLock` is not recursive, and ReaderWriterLockSlim is not recursive by default**"...There are several reasons why I think recursive locks are a poor choice in general, and only one situation where I think they could possibly be helpful](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html)_